# Hibernate with H2 getting errors when establishing entity manager (Eclipse/Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

below is the error I am receiving when I run the test class given to me for the assignment:

```
2019-11-14T19:58:38.309Z [34mINFO [0;39m [main      ] [36mc.a.cst8277.assignment3.Test[0;39m - setup JPA EntityManagerFactory, create EntityManager (Session)
2019-11-14T19:58:40.004Z [34mINFO [0;39m [main      ] [36meclipselink.logging.all[0;39m - EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041
2019-11-14T19:58:40.021Z [34mINFO [0;39m [main      ] [36meclipselink.logging.connection[0;39m - connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>H2Platform
    user name=> "sa"
    datasource URL=> "jdbc:h2:mem:Assignment3"
))
2019-11-14T19:58:40.429Z [34mINFO [0;39m [main      ] [36meclipselink.logging.connection[0;39m - Connected: jdbc:h2:mem:Assignment3
    User: SA
    Database: H2  Version: 1.4.199 (2019-03-13)
    Driver: H2 JDBC Driver  Version: 1.4.199 (2019-03-13)
2019-11-14T19:58:40.512Z [1;31mERROR[0;39m [main      ] [36meclipselink.logging.all[0;39m - Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [PORTFOLIO.PORTFOLIO_ID].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.algonquincollege.cst8277.assignment3.model.Portfolio --> [DatabaseTable(PORTFOLIO)])
```

The last portion repeats for all the classes and I also get another set of errors which also repeats for all the classes I have created:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.algonquincollege.cst8277.assignment3.model.Portfolio --> [DatabaseTable(PORTFOLIO)])
```

Here is the test class I need to run:

```
/**************************************************************G*********o****o****g**o****og**joob*********************
 * File: Test.java
 * Course materials (19F) CST 8277
 * @author Mike Norman
 *
 * @date 2019 10
 */
package com.algonquincollege.cst8277.assignment3;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.algonquincollege.cst8277.assignment3.dao.BankUserDAOImpl;

public class Test {

    private static final Class<?> _thisClaz = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(_thisClaz);

    public static final String ASSIGNMENT3_PU_NAME = "Assignment3-main-PU";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("setup JPA EntityManagerFactory, create EntityManager (Session)");
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ASSIGNMENT3_PU_NAME);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Here is one of the 8 classes in question, the error I posted specifically references this class/table but all others are setup similarly and have similar error messages:

```
package com.algonquincollege.cst8277.assignment3.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the PORTFOLIO database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Portfolio.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Portfolio p")
public class Portfolio extends ModelBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Asset> assets;

    public Portfolio() {
    }

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PORTFOLIO_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }



    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Asset
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="portfolio")
    public List<Asset> getAssets() {
        return this.assets;
    }

    public void setAssets(List<Asset> assets) {
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public Asset addAsset(Asset asset) {
        getAssets().add(asset);
        asset.setPortfolio(this);

        return asset;
    }

    public Asset removeAsset(Asset asset) {
        getAssets().remove(asset);
        asset.setPortfolio(null);

        return asset;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing *insertable* to *true* for `id` field. Like this:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PORTFOLIO_ID", insertable=true, updatable=false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
```